# Why does code work on Solaris but not on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, solaris

I have a `C` code which is working fine on `Solaris` machine but the same code is giving segmentation fault for sometimes and some other time producing different output.

The following is the part where I am getting difference in both the machines:

```
FILE *inf;
unsigned char *ptr;
unsigned short *ds;
int n, s; 
char work[100];

inf = (FILE *) fopen("Filename", "r");  
s = fseek(inf, 0, SEEK_SET);
n = fread(work, 1, sizeof(work), inf);
ptr = (unsigned char *)work;
ptr += 8;

count = 0;
ds = (unsigned short *) ptr;
count = *ds;
```

When I am printing the value of count it is `15` in `Solaris` Machine and `768` in `Linux` machine.

Please suggest me the changes to be done in code on Linux machine.

Comment: What endianness is the Solaris machine ?

Comment: There's no need to cast the return value of `fopen()`, don't do that. Also, you should of course check that all I/O calls succeed before relying on the results.

Comment: A file opened for reading is positioned at the start of the file.  The `fseek()` is redundant — but so redundant that it isn't a factor in your problem.  I assume that despite the absence of error checking, there isn't a problem with `fopen()` (in particular) failing.

Comment: Have you done a byte-by-byte dump of the value read into `work` on each machine?  Is it the same on each machine?  Did you check the value of `n`?  Your code asks to read up to 100 units of size 1, so you can get short reads (`n < 100`).  What is the data structure that's written to the file?  How is it written on the SPARC (Solaris) machine?  You use an offset of 8; are you sure that's correct?  Is the file being written on Solaris and read on Linux, or is it being written and read OK on Solaris, but failing when written and then read on Linux?

Comment: Whatever the details of the problem, you should aim to provide platform-neutral code — so the same source code works on both Linux (Intel, little-endian) and Solaris (SPARC, big-endian). It is perfectly doable; it just requires some care.  So, your "changes to code on Linux" comment worries me; you should be seeking "change to the code so it works on both Linux and Solaris".

Comment: Please provide the output of `od -N 64 -A d -t d1 Filename` for the file you're actually opening, on _both_ Solaris and Linux ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's (just) the endianness. 15 = 0x000F. 768 = 0x0300. It might be related to the size of char though. Try printing CHAR_BIT on both machines and see what you get.

Comment: Whatever the platform `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by standard and by design.

Comment: @Kalyan Urimi Have you tried it? You will have to add the limits header for this to work.

Comment: @KalyanUrimi It's 8 on both machines?